# IIS not logging users on local machine

Tags: .net, iis

I had my .NET App up and running on my local machine using my own IIS for a dev environnement with no problems. However, about 2 weeks ago we had to install a web certificate in ever pc inside the company, and today they asked me to make a small change in my app but I can't open my app on my local IIS: I'm using windows autehntification and even though I'm typing the right credentials, the window keeps popping out as if i'm typing them wrong. What is weird is that on chrome and edge my credentials are passing through and when I try to log in in any of this browsers from an external machine, everything works fine only on edge and only if I'm using my user. When I try to use other users credentials I can't get through the winodws autentification promp. I have no idea what to do, I haven't modifeid my IIS in any shape or form and I'm a little bit worried that if I deploy the app on my production IIS everyhting might break. Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Disable the famous loopback check via registry key and then try again.

Comment: How do I do that ? Do you have a resource?

Answer (score 0):

The following explains how to disable loopback check in IIS. In this method, you can simply disable the check by editing the following registry key.

1. Select Run from the Start menu, and then enter “regedit”.
2. Then navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`
3. Click on Lsa Registry and add DisableLoopbackCheck registry key as DWORD value.
4. After adding the registry key you can find the entry named “DisableLoopbackCheck”.
5. You need double-click the key and enter 1, then Click OK.
6. Restart the IIS.

Please refer to this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37337.disable-loopback-check-in-iis.aspx